# WMM/WME(802.11e) not working properly in 802.11n?

Tags: wireless-networking, qos, 802.11n, 802.11, 802.11g

I'm performing some tests regarding 802.11e (WMM/WME) performance and when doing up-link it isn't working properly.

Im using an Lynksys 1200ac with OpenWrt/LEDE as AP, and two PCs lets say PC1 and PC2, both PCs are using the same wireless card model (USB TP-Link TL-WN722N).

I'm testing WMM for up-link as you can see in next image:

[image: Test Architecture]

I have two flows, from the PC's to to the AP, one is Background traffic other is marked as voice traffic.

When i set the network to be 802.11g everything works fine, and i have a huge improvement using WMM, getting 10x more throughput.

But when i set the network to be 802.11n, WMM is not working as expected, Voice flows have only a small improvement over Background traffic:

*Voice flow is the green line after 40s*
[image: Voice flow is the green line after 40s]

I wonder if you could help me figure this out, the main difference is that for 802.11n there is aggregation (A-MSDU) happening and I'm getting block acks instead of individual packets acks.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use Video (VI) instead of voice (VO) for the higher-priority stream? I've seen some chipsets/drivers allocate buffers with the assumption that the voice queue really is only carrying actual voice traffic; low bandwidth streams of tiny packets, evenly spaced, that need minimal latency and jitter. Trying to shoe-horn a full-speed large-packet TCP stream into the voice queue doesn't work well on those chipsets. The Video queue usually doesn't have that problem as much.

Comment: Your using AES and not TKIP right?

Comment: Using the video queue do not make any difference.

Comment: Open network without encryption.